# Forward packets between SR-IOV Virtual Function (VF) NICs

Tags: virtualization, qemu, dpdk

I have an Intel 82599ES 10G NIC which supports Intel SR-IOV. I have successfully created 8 virtual functions (VF) of it and assigned to 2 qemu/kvm VMs (2 VFs per each VM). Both of the VMs run DPDK applications (warp17 on one and my custom application on other) using assigned VFs. What I need to do is test my custom DPDK application by sending traffic through it using warp17. My test setup looks like this,
The red arrow represents the traffic path.

[image: VF and VM Configuration]

My Physical NIC (PF) use dpdk poll mode driver (igb_uio). What I need to do is route traffic between VFs as shown by the red arrows. I think https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/prog_guide/switch_representation.html has explained switching behavior but I cannot understand it. warp17 and my custom dpdk application both works perfectly on physical hardware. What I trying to do is virtualize my test setup to preserve resources. Has anyone tried to do such configuration?

Comment: hi @Anuradha, you have mentioned `82599ES ` as NIC but in the figure it is `X710`. cab you please confirm your NIC, Firmware, DPDK version to start with

Comment: hi @VipinVarghese I have previously used x710 but I had to use it for some other task so I'm now using 82599ES. SR-IOV worked on both NICs. My dpdk version is 16.11.2.

Comment: thanks for the update, I have updated with the answer.

Comment: I just need to know how to configure this setup ( or is it even possible?).

Comment: as answered there is no asicv function in X710 or 82599ES, So you have use SW switch or application to do the same with virtio ports or tap interface. If you want to use with physical NIC from X710 or 82599ES you will physical connectivity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

neither X710 `fortville` and Ninatic `82599ES` ASIC does not have internal Bridging or forwarding `VERB`or `feature`. The best option is to have software virtual switch like `SPP`, `OVS-DPDK` or custom application to forward packets via virtio or tap.

if you still want to use physical NIC or x710 or 82599ES you will need to have connection at other end and run the logic to direct packets to relevant VF (modifying dst mac).

Edit-1: (as per DPDK 20.11) VEB virtual ethernet Bridging is an option, but specific NIC firmware and driver is required to create VEB on PF then propagate to VF. Once done the NIC can not receive packets from the Outside world

Comment: thanks for the answer. My virtual functions are not bonded to host kernal using a driver. Is it possible to bind them to both host and guest kernals and use testpmd to do the forwarding?

Comment: can you explain this better (figure if possible).

Comment: Sorry for confusion. I think it's not possible to do(what I asked). I will try with SPP or OVS and post the results here. Thank you!

Comment: thanks for confirming, please accept and upvote to help the question to reach others.